# Azure Pipelines refuses to create a GitHub release

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure release pipeline to build my app and create a GitHub release, but that step is getting skipped:

> 2020-03-08T16:32:07.1704675Z ##[warning]Release will not be created as the tags for the target commit do not match with the given tag pattern.

But I never specified any "tag pattern" and i don't see anywhere to change it. What is the message talking about? How can I get my binaries created and uploaded to GitHub?

Comment: Could you share your GitHub release create task?

Comment: Yeah, it's really simple: https://pastebin.com/NMPvpT3M

Comment: @ekolis Not get your latest information, if the below answer is helpful to you ,would you please mark it as an answer. Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Sorry, I have yet to push changes to the repo in question recently, so I'm not sure if this change worked or not. Is there a way to force a build? Azure is so confusing...

Comment: @ekolis `Is there a way to force a build?` What are you referring to? Please give a detailed description.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Force a build, as in run the pipeline without an actual commit to the master branch to trigger it.

Answer (score 2):

> [warning]Release will not be created as the tags for the target commit
>   do not match with the given tag pattern

This warning is caused by `Tag Pattern` property of the GitHub release task. If the Tag Pattern property in the task is empty, this could cause warning, this is because the Tag Pattern property is **Required**.

This is stated in the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/github-release?view=azure-devops):

> Tag   (**Required**) Specify the tag for which you want to create, edit, or
>   discard a release. You can also use variables here. E.g. $(tagName).
>
> Tag source    (**Required**) Configure the tag to be used for release
>   creation. The 'Git tag' option **automatically takes the tag which is**
>   **associated with this commit**. Use the 'User specified tag' option in
>   case you want to manually provide a tag.

[image]

To resolve this issue, we need to give the Tag Pattern with corresponding tag or expression.

Comment: Oh, interesting. So what pattern do I use to make it run every time I push changes to the master branch? Would that be `.*`?

Comment: Decide on the strategy you want to go for - either versioning each release or using custom tags. 1. If you use `Git tag` option ,as the description above, the 'Git tag' option automatically takes the tag which is associated with this commit. Here is a [blog](https://bauermalzwei.de/2020/01/19/creating-github-releases-with-azure-pipelines/) you can refer to. If there is no tag for commit, you can give the Tag Pattern with the commit ID.

Comment: 2. If you don't want to specify a tag for each commit, you could use the another option `User specified tag`, then you can manually provide a tag, like release-v1.0.0 or use `$(Build.BuildNumber)` to use the version number used in the build.